# SBT project for java executable jar

Tags: scala, executable-jar, sbt

What is the best way to set the target package for an SBT project to be an executable jar file?

It would need to bundle scala-library.jar and set the manifest for main-method.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar. I haven't tried myself but I'm interested to know if that works. Also if that does not work, retronym also points to https://github.com/nuttycom/sbt-proguard-plugin.

Comment: Thanks huynhjl. It worked fine, but I decided against it as one-jar itself seems full of classloading jiggery-pokery. I prefer the mega-jar approach of assembly-sbt.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the assembly-sbt plugin (originally created by Coda Hale, now maintained by [Eugene Yokota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827/eugene-yokota)): https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Once you add this to your project it will build a so-called "fatjar" which is executable via `java -jar projectName-assembly.jar`. It will autodetect your main method -- if there is more than one in your source, you can explicitly set which one to use by setting `mainclass`, e.g.:

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.package.ClassNameWithMain")
```

*Note: I edited this answer to be up-to-date with the current release of SBT (0.11+).*

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It's a good one. Simple to use. Would benefit from having proguard trim out the fat.

Comment: You can use the Proguard plugin to do that. Make sure you specify that you want to keep the main class.

Comment: Yes, Proguard can do this, but it's a pain to configure correctly. The beauty of the sbt-assembly is how incredibly simple it is.

Comment: @folone I tried this using assembly and generated jar but still it won't execute using double click. How do I create executable jar which will run when you click on it?